# Why won't android emulators work on my Macbook?

Tags: mac, android, macbook, emulator

I've tried to use all sorts of android emulators, such as Bluestacks, Nox, and even ARC Welder from Chrome) on my Macbook (late 2009 with 10.12 Sierra). When I tried to open them after they finished downloading, they were always stuck on the loading screen with the progress bar on 100%. ARC Welder wouldn't even open the apk file of the android app I wanted to open.

What android emulator will work on my Macbook? Do I need to download something to help run android emulators on my Macbook?

Answer (score 1):

The Macbook late 2009 uses a Intel Core 2 Duo CPU.

Unfortunately this CPU is too old, it does not contain hardware virtualization technology support, which is a requirement for nearly every Android emulator. In detail this should be AFAIK the features Extended Page Tables (EPT) and Unrestricted Guest (UG).

As this is a hardware problem this can't be solved by software. The only way would be an Android emulator that does not require those CPU features, but I am not sure if such an emulator software really exists.